# I use old dart code in 2020 and my update Dart SKD shows all error

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I repeadtely get this erro while iusing ht eold version of sdk dat, but I did not use the old flutter.
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.3.

Because food_delivery depends on cupertino_icons >=0.1.1 <1.0.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '<2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev.28.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.

```
name: food_delivery
description: A new Flutter project.


environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth:
  firebase:
  cloud_firestore:
  google_sign_in : ^4.0.7
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0
  firebase_storage:
  font_awesome_flutter:
  image_picker:
  firebase_database:
  geolocator:
  google_maps_flutter:



  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  #cupertino_icons: ^<latest-version>

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  bloc_pattern:
  rxdart:



  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/1.png
    - assets/google.png
    - assets/moto.png
    - assets/map.png
    - assets/foodtukk.png
    - assets/foodtukk1.png

    - family: Quicksand
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Medium.ttf
          style: normal
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand_Bold.otf
          weight: 700

    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
          style: normal
        - asset: assets/fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf
```

Comment: Just remove `cupertino_icons` from the dependencies. You probably don't use it, do you

Comment: I did but, it is  rise another issue
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.3.

Because food_delivery depends on cupertino_icons >=0.1.1 <1.0.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '<2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev.28.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
```

with

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.1 <4.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer
I did so, but it did not effect

Answer (score 0):

This type of error happens because of mismatch between used dependencies and supported sdk versions.

```
Because bitcoin_ticker depends on cupertino_icons >=0.1.1 <1.0.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.
```

For e.g. here the `cupertino_icons >=0.1.1 <1.0.1` doesn't support null safety and hence the error is very clear that to support null safety you must be on 2.12.0 or higher

```
The lower bound of "sdk: '<2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev.28.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
```

Now when I was facing the problem below was configuration in my pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

Updated it to below

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.1.4 <4.0.0"
```

Now because we have updated the sdk version, you should also use the latest version of cupertino_icons

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
```

Now it should work perfectly fine.